# jQuery credit card validator only on submit or click

Tags: jquery

I'm using [jQuery Credit Card Validator](http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/) to validate a credit card number.

the documentation says :

> The plugin uses inputevent with a fallback to keyup. That means, in most browsers, it will run the callback every time the value changes: regardless of how the change was initiated (keystroke, paste, undo, redo, etc). In browsers that don’t support input event, the callback will be called only when the user releases a key on their keyboard keyup.

I do not want the check to accure on the input key press, I want to do a check when a button is pressed like :

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#card_number').validateCreditCard(function(result) {
        if (!result.valid) {
            alert("invalid card");
        }
    });
```

How can I prevent the key press check and make the check only on button click? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like that plugin provides any customization features like that. It just works the way it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the event bindings after performing the check.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#card_number').validateCreditCard(function(result) {
        if (!result.valid) {
            alert("invalid card");
        }
    });
    $("#card_number").off('input.jccv keyup.jccv');
});
```